# Styled checkbox shows wrong box checked

Tags: php, css

I have a list of artists (a very long list) populated from a database and for every artist there is an edit checkbox and a delete checkbox. There is a submit button (not included, works ok). I have not included the code for the edit/delete process as I know these work.

I have styled the checkboxes with css. For the purposes of testing I have not removed the standard checkboxes.

When I click the standard checkboxes for any artist they perform correctly and show the the checkbox is checked. However when I do the same for the styled checkboxes only the first checkbox shows that it is checked. Example: click 5th artist checkbox, 1st artist checkbox shows that it is checked.

Inspector shows that each checkbox shows the correct value for both the standard and styled checkbox.

Cannot find similar problem on the net, so guys any ideas. Many Thanks.

artist.php code
———————————————-

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();

$artists = get_artists($_GET['artist_id']);

$artist_id = $_GET['artist_id'];
$id = $artist_id;


if (!empty($_POST['edit'])) {
foreach ($_POST['edit'] as $artist_id) {
header("Location: artist_edit.php?artist_id=$artist_id");
exit();
}   
}else{
if (!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
foreach ($_POST['delete'] as $artist_id) {
artist_delete($artist_id);
header('Location: artist_list.php');
exit();
}
}
}   
?>
<h1>Artist List</h1>


<?php
foreach ($artists as $artist) {
echo '
<tr>
<td class="alt1" align="center" valign="middle">
<input name="edit[]" type="checkbox" value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
</td>
<td class="alt1" align="center" valign="middle">
<input name="delete[]" type="checkbox" value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
</td>
<td class="alt1" align="center" valign="middle">
<div class="checkboxone">
<input type="checkbox" name="edit[]" id="checkboxoneinput" value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
<label for="checkboxoneinput"></label>
</div>
</td>
<td class="alt1" align="center" valign="middle">
<div class="checkboxtwo">
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="checkboxtwoinput" value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
<label for="checkboxtwoinput"></label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</td>
</tr>
';
}
?>
```

css code [code for checkboxone and checkboxtwo are identical]
————————-

```
/*input[type=checkbox] {
visibility: hidden;
}*/
.checkboxone {
width: 25px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}
.checkboxone label {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(11, 78, 126, 0.5);
border:1px solid rgba(11, 78, 126, 0.5);
border-radius: 4px;
}
.checkboxone label:after {
opacity: 0.1;
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 8px;
height: 4px;
background: transparent;
top:3px;
left: 2px;
border: 3px solid #fff;
border-top: none;
border-right: none;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.checkboxone label:hover::after {
opacity: 0.4;
}
.checkboxone input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: side note: You have `id="checkboxoneinput"` and `id="checkboxtwoinput"` in your `foreach ($artists)` loop, which means you will have `count($artists)` number of duplicate `id`s, and `id`s should be unique. may not affect you now, but might in the future.

Answer (score 3):

When you click on a styled checkbox, you are clicking on a label. The label is attached to the `id` of its matching checkbox by the `for` attribute and they must be unique for each loop.

If we look at your php:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="checkboxtwoinput" value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
<label for="checkboxtwoinput"></label>
```

Notice how the `for` attribute will always have the value `checkboxtwoinput` and the `id` attribute will always have that same value. Every label will select that first checkbox.

Make a unique ID and for attribute for each input like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="checkTwo ' . $artist['artist_id'] . ' " value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
<label for="checkTwo ' . $artist['artist_id'] . ' "></label>
```

and do the same for the first checkbox **using "checkOne" before the artist id**. Each label will have a unique ID and for attribute matching the artist_id.

Of course you can use an integer variable instead of the artist id if you want:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($artists as $artist) {

    <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="checkTwo ' . $i . ' " value="',$artist['artist_id'],'">
    <label for="checkTwo ' . $i . ' "></label>

    ++$i;
}
```